# openSUSE:Build Service - Way to find all link packages

Tags: opensuse

I configured OpenBuildService with version 2.5.
And I have project called `TestProject` with 100 packages.
**The question is:** How can I list up all `link` packages?
I know the API to check whether the package is linked or not,

```
http://myserver:81/source/TestProject/samplepackage?rev=latest
```

I can't find the API to list up whole linked package list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution.
`info` option exist.

Thanks.